# Access Query to count transactions not like 

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create an Access query to count all the distinct transactions that don´t contain the characters (V). My data looks like this:

```
Transaction Number
997
997
998
998
998
999
999(V)
```

The final result I would like to get is "2" (997 and 998), so I can eliminate the 2 records ( 999 and 999(V) ). I was thinking in counting all rows and then substract all rows that contain (V), but can´t select the (V)´s. This is the query I have and It gives me 0 all the time and not 1:

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) AS C
FROM         (SELECT DISTINCT [Transaction Number]
                   FROM          [Product History]
                   WHERE      ([Transaction Date] = #7/6/2011#) AND ([Transaction Number] LIKE '*V*')) T
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. I chose to use  `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` you could also do `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`

the key is joining `ph1.[Transaction Number] & '(V)' = ph2.[Transaction Number]`

```
SELECT COUNT ([Transaction Number]) as C
  FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT ph1.[Transaction Number]
        FROM  [Product History] ph1
                            LEFT JOIN [Product History] ph2
                            ON ph1.[Transaction Number] & '(V)' = ph2.[Transaction Number] 
                             WHERE     
                               ph1.[Transaction Date] = #7/6/2011#
                               and ph1.[Transaction Number] NOT LIKE '%V%'
                               and ph2.[Transaction Number] is null) t;
```

which outputs

```
C           
----------- 
2
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that using both statements LIKE and NOT LIKE and can´t get count = 1 for the single record that contains (V). I always get 0. I can get the count 4 of the  distinct records using NOT LIKE, but now I want to get the V record to substract it from the previous count, which by the way is not the number I want because that will give me 3. In other words, the V means (Void), so I want to know how many transactions not void I have, so I can´t count 999 as transaction becuase it was voided with 999(V).

Comment: WOW!! I´ve been "fighting" with this query for a few hours now and I was not even close! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! It works exactly as I wanted. I hope some day to pay you back. =0)